# Multiple inheritance. What is the idea behind this inheritance model for implementing `+=`?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

For a C++ class I am trying to design a class hierarchy that handles binary operations `+=`  and `-=`. The desired hierarchy (per question requirements) is described as follows. We have two classes `Addition` and `Subtraction`. These are base classes for a class `Binops`. Then a class `Operations` inherits from `Binops`. So the diagram would look like this

```
       Operations
           |
           ↓
        Binops 
         |  |
         |  |
     +---+  +---+
     ↓          ↓
  Addition  Subtraction
```

Here `Binops` is a friend class of `Operations`. The following member functions are required: `Operations` implements the private functions

```
void add(Operations const &rhs);
void sub(Operations const &rhs);
```

And the class `Addition` needs to implement

```
Addition::operator+=(Operations const &rhs)
```

Similarly for the `Subtraction` class.

I have questions about both the implementation of this design as well as the idea behind it.

The way I see it, once this framework is ready, another class like for instance a `Matrix` class could inherit from the `Operations` class and then we make `Matrix` a friend of `Operations` so `Matrix` can use `+=` etc. Then we would simply have to implement the `add` function in `Operations` and the `+=` operation would then work for the `Matrix` class. But then why don't we simply implement the `+=` operator in `Operations` or even `Matrix`? Maybe the idea is that we can also define the `=` operator in `Addition` using the `add` function `Operations`, so that after implementing `add`, both `+=` and `+` work in one go.

From an implementation standpoint: What should be the return type of `+=` in `Addition`? I believe it should be `Operations`, but then the `Addition` class header should include the `Operations` header which results in circular dependencies.

Furthermore, for `Addition` to be able to use `add` from `Operations`, is there some way we can do that without making `Addition` a friend of `Operations` too? I do not think simply making `Addition` a friend of `Binops` is enough as friendship is not transitive.

Sorry for the long question. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Your inheritance seems backward. Addition is a special type of binary operation, not the other way around.

Comment: Wrong place to ask. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place (but probably not). Read more about smart pointers http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Comment: Unclear. "a class Operations inherits from this Binops" and "Binops is a friend class of Operations". So which is it. Is it a friend class or a subclass. A subclass that's also a friend class is not a good design. The fact that -- as it's been pointed out -- the inheritance is backwards seems to reinforce the notion that the overall class design is wrong.

Comment: @LogicStuff All the arrows are pointing up, though.

Comment: @chepner You are right, The arrows should be the other way around, will fix! These diagrams can be confusing

Comment: @chepner `HasAllOperations` inheirts from `HasBinops` which inherits from `HasAddition`.

Comment: Digram aside, `BinOps` should be the base class of `Addition` and `Subtraction`, not the other way around.

Comment: @chepner I thought the same thing would make more sense as `Addition` IS a binary operation (+=). However, exact wording of the question "Furthermore, Addition and Subtraction are base classes of a class Binops" The comments so far seem to indicate that there are some fundamental problems here. Perhaps I should delete the question and discuss with the professor to determine if he may have made a mistake.

Comment: @Slugger Re "Addition and Subtraction are base classes of a class Binops": That could be translated to "BinOps  IS AN addition **and** IS A Subtraction". That doesn't seem to make sense. Bjarne S.' multiple inheritance example is something like "a window is a paintable **and** a scrollable" which makes much more sense.

Comment: *"What is the idea behind this inheritance model (...)?"* - Answer: over-engineering. That's not a good example to explain object-oriented theory, nor is it of any practical use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears those class names are a bit off.  My psychic decoding is that `Addition` is `HasAddition`.  So we have `HasOperations` inherits from `HasBinOps`, which inherits from both `HasAddition` and `HasSubtraction`.

So I get the basic plan.  But I'm going to answer how to do this right.  This may not line up with your assignment, but that is honestly your assignment's problem not mine!

We do not want virtual runtime dispatch and dynamic allocation going on for all basic operations.  We want static polymorphism, not dynamic polymorphism.

Luckily, in C++ we have static polymorphism.  A typical way to implement it is via the CRTP -- the curiously repeating template pattern.

We do not have to use CRTP here.  We can instead rely on Koenig lookup!

Koenig lookup is the fact that when determing what `operator+` to call, your parent classes `friend`s are considered.  We inject a `friend operator+` that matches on *derived types* by making it a `template` inside `has_addition`.

When we have our `matrix:has_addition`, and we invoke `+`. this template is found.  And we then substitute the type of the arguments -- the full type, not the `has_addition` parent type.

In this full type, we have a `.add` method.

So we can inherit from a type such that the `operator+` in that type has a different implementation based on what the type we derive from it, but this dispatch is done statically at compile time.

At runtime, `has_addition` basically disappears.  Instead, we just get a bunch of `+`'s routed to `.add`.

So, without further ado, here is `has_addition`:

```
struct has_addition {
  // implement + in terms of += on the lhs:
  template<class L, class R>
  friend std::decay_t<L> operator+( L&& lhs, R&& rhs ) {
    if (!std::is_reference<L>{}) { // rvalue lhs
      return std::forward<L>(lhs) += rhs;
    } else if (!std::is_reference<R>{}) { // rvalue rhs
      return std::forward<R>(rhs) += lhs; // assumes + commutes
    } else { // rvalue neither
      auto tmp = std::forward<L>(lhs);
      return tmp += rhs;
    }
  }
  // notice += on an rvalue returns a copy.
  // This permits reference lifetime extension:
  template<class L, class R>
  friend L operator+=( L&& lhs, R&& rhs ) {
    lhs.add( std::forward<R>(rhs) );
    return std::forward<L>(lhs);
  }
};
```

you use it via:

```
struct bob : has_addition {
  int x = 0;
  void add( bob const& rhs ) {
    x += rhs.x;
  }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cd6f62cebc0d46c).

Now both `+` and `+=` are implemented for you based on your `add` method.  What more, there are multiple rvalue and lvalue overloads of them.  If you implement move-construct, you get automatic performance boosts.  If you implement add that takes an rvalue on the right hand side, you get automatic performance boosts.

If you fail to write the rvalue overloaded `add` and move-construct, things still work.  We decoupled the factors (adding something you can discard, and recycling your storage, and micro-optimization of how `+` works) from each other.  The result is easier to write code with piles of micro optimizations built-in.

Now most of the micro-optimizations in `has_addition::operator+` are not required for a first pass.

```
struct has_addition {
  // implement + in terms of += on the lhs:
  template<class L, class R>
  friend L operator+( L lhs, R&& rhs ) {
    return std::move(lhs) += std::forward<R>(rhs);
  }
  template<class L, class R>
  friend L operator+=( L&& lhs, R&& rhs ) {
    lhs.add( std::forward<R>(rhs) );
    return std::forward<L>(lhs);
  }
};
```

which is much cleaner and nearly optimal.

---

We then extend this with

```
struct has_subtraction; // implement
struct has_binops:
  has_subtraction,
  has_addition
{};

struct has_operations:
  has_binops
{};
```

but really, few types have every type of operation, so I personally wouldn't like this.

You could use SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error) to detect if `add`, `subtact`, `multiply`, `divide`, `order`, `equals` etc are implemented in your type, and write `maybe_has_addition<D>` that does a SFINAE test on `D` to determine if it has `D.add( D const& )` implemented.  If and only if so `has_addition` is inherited from `maybe_has_addition<D>`.

Then you can set it up so that a whole myriad of operator overloads are written by doing:

```
struct matrix: maybe_has_operations<matrix>
```

where as you implement new operations on `matrix`, more and more overloaded operators kick in.

This, however, is a different problem.

---

Doing this with dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions) is a mess.  And really, do you want to jump through multiple vtables, dynamic allocations, and lose all compile time type safety when you write `matrix1 = matrix2 + matrix3`?  This isn't Java.

---

The friend bit is pretty easy.  Notice how `has_addition` calls `D.add(D const&)`.  We can make `add` private within `D`, but only if we `friend struct has_addition;` within the body of `D`.

So `has_addition` is both a parent of `D` and a friend of `D`.

Myself, I just leave `add` exposed, because it is harmless.

---

This technique has downsides, like what happens when you add two distinct classes both of which `has_addition`.

You can see a more fleshed-out version of this in [boost.operators](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.operators), which uses related techniques as well.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate and clear answer! This seems like a very nice way of doing things, and certainly much nicer than having a nested inheritance structure as described in the question. The CRTP idiom is something I haven't seen before but it looks really useful! Thanks again!

Comment: @Slugger Btw, I noticed it had issues, and is is revised and cleaner now.  CRTP is not required here!